# What is the field of owner of opportunity in SAP B1 SDK?

Tags: sdk, sapb1

I added Opportunity in SAP B1 by using SDK it's fine, but I have one problem, the field of Owner I used is DataOwnershipfield but it adds nothing, there is no error returned data added successfully but no Owner. I even tried to use DocumentsOwner which is used in documents it returns error message Unable to lookup DocumentsOwner

What is the real field of Owner in SAP B1 SDK?

Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SAP 9.3 PL06 that I've tried it the following code works:

```
SalesOpportunities oOpport = oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oSalesOpportunities);
oOpport.DataOwnershipfield = 5;
```

The `DataOwnershipfield` attribute is the owner field. It is an integer corresponding to the empID from the Employee Master Data table (OHEM)

**EDIT:**

There is the possibility that on `oOpport.Add();` the opportunity is successfully added but the Owner not, however on `oOpport.Update();` it is successfully added.

I would suggest a check after each Add and if the owner is not successfully added to update it. (on a sample of 20 examples, 3 failed with no obvious consistency)